# How to create spec for new major library version?

Tags: cocoapods

I've recently released version 4 of [SBJson](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/releases/tag/v4.0.0). This is a new major version that is *not* backwards compatible. Since SBJson is widely bundled by other popular libraries I renamed all the classes & enums to make sure it can be used in conjunction with prior versions.

However, I'm not sure how to best handle this situation with CocoaPods. I contributed a [4.0.0 spec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/SBJson/4.0.0/SBJson.podspec) to the existing SBJson specs, but I suspect it will be impossible to install version 3.2 and 4.0.0 in the same project. Do I have to clone the 4.0.0 spec into a `SBJson4` (notice extra major version number in name) spec as well?

Comment: When would it be necessary for both version to work in a single project?

Comment: Keith, whenever you want to use it in conjunction with one of the 100s of libraries that depend on earlier versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Morning.

If you want users to have both versions installed simultaneously they will probably have to be separate pods.

AFAIK you can't have one pod installed twice in a project. I don't even know how you'd get round the linker errors etc. for that to be possible!

Comment: Doesn't look like anyone else has any ideas, even after you added the bounty!